# Promise always undefined

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to call an API and use the results but the promise result is always coming back as undefined.

I think this should be straight forward, but I'm new to promises and I've spent many hours trying to figure this out without any luck. I've tried so many versions. I want to

1. Call an API

   - The API will return JSON in which I am interested in an array of numbers within it
2. Parse the JSON to get that array
3. Use the array in another function to do something

Initially I had these two functions

```
//Get the references
function getReferences(articleID) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("get", "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=pubmed&linkname=pubmed_pubmed_refs&retmode=json&id=" + articleID + "&api_key=0&tool=my_tool2&email=my_email@example.com", false);
    request.send();

    var obj = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    return obj.linksets[0].linksetdbs[0].links;
}

//use the references
function useReferences(startingArticleID) {
    var references = getReferences(startingArticleID);
    // do something with the array "references"
}
```

and this worked well except sometimes `getReferences` would try to parse before the API call was complete. So I modified the code to look like this (used Axios to try to help with API calling)

```
async function getReferences(articleID) {
    let json = await axios.get("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?  dbfrom=pubmed&linkname=pubmed_pubmed_refs&retmode=json&id=" + articleID  + "&api_key=0&tool=my_tool2&email=my_email@example.com");
    return json;
}

async function useReferences(startingArticleID) {
    let references = await getReferences(startingArticleID); 
    //do something with the array references
}
```

But `references` always comes back as `undefined` with a status of pending. I read and experimented with `.then()` but the value from the promise was still `undefined`.

Comment: change `getReferences` function to `function getReferences(articleID){ return axios.get("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?  dbfrom=pubmed&linkname=pubmed_pubmed_refs&retmode=json&id=" + articleID  + "&api_key=0&tool=my_tool2&email=my_email@example.com"); }`

Comment: Is there any reason you have spaces after `fcgi?` on the axios function?

Comment: Have you tried to console.log your json after the `await axios.get`? What does it show?

Comment: when I run your second piece of code using [this url](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts), I'm able to get the response. Have you double checked your URL, like the other comments have also pointed out?

Comment: Thanks everybody. The spaces in the URL are just on SO not in app, my debugger stopped working so I just got that fixed and I'm seeing the functions are flowing very strangely. I have a simple index.html page which calls useReferences() and what is happening is that after the statement "let references = await getReferences(startingArticleID)" the function is returning back to the the index page.
relevant part of the index page:

    `<script>

        var refs = useReferences(1396582); // <- goes back to here too early as promise undefined

        var tdata = JSON.parse(refs);`